# ElasticSearch returning only documents with distinct value

Tags: java, elasticsearch, aggregate, spring-data-elasticsearch, nosql

Let's say I have this given data

```
{
            "name" : "ABC",
            "favorite_cars" : [ "ferrari","toyota" ]
          }, {
            "name" : "ABC",
            "favorite_cars" : [ "ferrari","toyota" ]
          }, {
            "name" : "GEORGE",
            "favorite_cars" : [ "honda","Hyundae" ]
          }
```

Whenever I query this data when searching for people who's favorite car is toyota, it returns this data

```
{

            "name" : "ABC",
            "favorite_cars" : [ "ferrari","toyota" ]
          }, {
            "name" : "ABC",
            "favorite_cars" : [ "ferrari","toyota" ]
          }
```

the result is Two records of with a name of ABC. How do I select distinct documents only?  The result I want to get is only this

```
{
                "name" : "ABC",
                "favorite_cars" : [ "ferrari","toyota" ]
              }
```

Here's my Query

```
{
    "fuzzy_like_this_field" : {
        "favorite_cars" : {
            "like_text" : "toyota",
            "max_query_terms" : 12
        }
    }
}
```

I am using ElasticSearch 1.0.0. with the java api client

Comment: Why wouldn't GEORGE be returned? What is your query? This question needs more details to be useful (and answereable)

Comment: @Burkhard I updated my question. Change the favor of George to Hyundae

Answer (score 21):

You can eliminate duplicates using [aggregations](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/_executing_aggregations.html). With [term aggregation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html) the results will be grouped by one field, e.g. `name`, also providing a count of the ocurrences of each value of the field, and will sort the results by this count (descending).

```
{
  "query": {
    "fuzzy_like_this_field": {
      "favorite_cars": {
        "like_text": "toyota",
        "max_query_terms": 12
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "grouped_by_name": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "name",
        "size": 0
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In addition to the `hits`, the result will also contain the `buckets` with the unique values in `key` and with the count in `doc_count`:

```
{
  "took" : 4,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 2,
    "max_score" : 0.19178301,
    "hits" : [ {
      "_index" : "pru",
      "_type" : "pru",
      "_id" : "vGkoVV5cR8SN3lvbWzLaFQ",
      "_score" : 0.19178301,
      "_source":{"name":"ABC","favorite_cars":["ferrari","toyota"]}
    }, {
      "_index" : "pru",
      "_type" : "pru",
      "_id" : "IdEbAcI6TM6oCVxCI_3fug",
      "_score" : 0.19178301,
      "_source":{"name":"ABC","favorite_cars":["ferrari","toyota"]}
    } ]
  },
  "aggregations" : {
    "grouped_by_name" : {
      "buckets" : [ {
        "key" : "abc",
        "doc_count" : 2
      } ]
    }
  }
}
```

Note that using aggregations will be costly because of duplicate elimination and result sorting.

Comment: How would I get that unique element through buckets? it only contains key

Comment: PS : fuzzy_like_this_field is deprecated in ES 1.6 https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-flt-field-query.html

Comment: Is there a way to target the array values themself instead of just the 'terms' inside the arrays. For arrays containing values like this ['mercedes slk', 'bmw 320'], i'm getting ['mercedes', 'slk', 'bmw', '320'] as aggregated keys back.

Comment: See this answer for how to use `top_hits` to pull in the first result - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34878356/select-distinct-values-of-bool-query-elastic-search#answer-34902873

Answer (score 9):

ElasticSearch doesn't provide any query by which you can get distinct documents based a field value.

Ideally you should have indexed the same document with same **type** and **id** since these two things are used by ElasticSearch to give a **_uid** unique id to a document. Unique id is important not only because of its way of detecting duplicate documents but also updating the same document in case of any modification instead of inserting a new one. For more information about indexing documents you can read [this](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/index-doc.html).

But there is definitely a work around for your problem. Since you are using java api client, you can remove duplicate documents based on a field value on your own. Infact, it gives you more flexibility to perform custom operations on the responses that you get from ES.

```
SearchResponse response = client.prepareSearch().execute().actionGet();
SearchHits hits = response.getHits();

Iterator<SearchHit> iterator = hits.iterator();
Map<String, SearchHit> distinctObjects = new HashMap<String,SearchHit>();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    SearchHit searchHit = (SearchHit) iterator.next();
    Map<String, Object> source = searchHit.getSource();
    if(source.get("name") != null){
        distinctObjects.put(source.get("name").toString(),source);
    }

}
```

So, you will have a map of unique searchHit objects in your map.

You can also create an object mapping and use that in place of SearchHit.

I hope this solves your problem. Please forgive me if there are any errors in the code. This is just a pseudo-ish code to make you understand how you can solve your problem.

Thanks

Comment: This approach is making it difficult to deal with paging. Since some elements can be removed on each page, the number of results on each page can be off.

Comment: I vote up, because the answer help the asker (and to get two votes and unlock bounty).

Answer (score 3):

@JRL is almost corrrect.  You will need an aggregation in your query.  This will get you a list of the top 10000 "favorite_cars" in your object ordered by occurance.

```
{
    "query":{ "match_all":{ } },
    "size":0,
    "Distinct" : {
        "Cars" : {
            "terms" : { "field" : "favorite_cars", "order": { "_count": "desc"}, "size":10000 }
         }
    }
}
```

It is also worth noting that you are going to want your "favorite_car" field to not be analyzed in order to get "McLaren F1" instead of "McLaren ", "F1".

```
"favorite_car": {
    "type": "string",
    "index": "not_analyzed"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For a single shard this can be handled using custom filter which also takes care of pagination. To handle the above use case we can use the script support as follows:

- Define a custom script filter. For this discussion assume it is called AcceptDistinctDocumentScriptFilter
- This custom filter takes in a list of primary keys as input.
- These primary keys are the fields whose values will be used to determine uniqueness of records.
- Now, instead of using aggregation we use normal search request and pass the custom script filter to the request.
- If the search already has a filter\query criteria defined then append the custom filter using logical AND operator.
- Following is example using pseudo syntax
      if the request is: 
          select * from myindex where file_hash = 'hash_value'
      then append the custom filter as:
          select * from myindex where file_hash = 'hash_value' AND AcceptDistinctDocumentScriptFilter(params= ['file_name', 'file_folder'])

For distributed search this is tricky and needs plugin to hook into QUERY phase. More details [here](http://exploring-elasticsearch.blogspot.in/2015/01/get-distinctunique-values-using-search.html).

Comment: While is is nice that you provided an answer, it's better to paste the information here and then cite the source. (links may become unreachable in time)

Comment: Added brief summary of the solution using custom script filter.