# Elasticsearch returning distinct results

Tags: elasticsearch, distinct

Here is my ES query:

```
  {
    "fields": [
      "news.authorname.raw",
      "news.authorid"
    ],
    "query": {
      "filtered": {
        "filter": {
          "terms": {
            "news.authorid": [
              1,
              2
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

With this query I get a list of pairs {authorid, authorname}. This list has repeated {authorid, authorname} values and I just need to get the same list but with no repetitions. This seems not that difficult or at least that is what I thought this morning. My small knowledge of ES together with the lack of documentation is making me desperate to find a solution to such a trivial problem.

Of course I could get the whole list and remove repetitions through code, but if it was possible I would prefere not to receive unnecessary data to have it removed afterwards.

Anyone can give a hand on that? Should I use some other approach?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Take at look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24508191/elasticsearch-returning-only-documents-with-distinct-value)

Comment: Ok I see, but does this mean there is no way to get the result ('hits' array) filtered with distinct values? I mean, I need to 'select distinct' by authorid, so 'bucket' array is not useful to me (an array of ids tells nothing in frontend) and the 'hits' array still contains duplicated values. I am starting to think I need to do it like this and filter distinct values by code. By now I will do so but if someone can please confirm whether this is the only way or there is some workaround to have results distinct-filtered straight straight from ES result I would really appreciate. Thanks btw!!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use [source filtering](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-source-filtering.html):

```
  {
    "_source": [ "news.authorname.raw", "news.authorid" ],
    "query": {
      "filtered": {
        "filter": {
          "terms": {
            "news.authorid": [
              1,
              2
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

It is generally easier to handle than fields, which sometimes do look like a cartesian product.

Comment: Thanks nefo_x, I have tried it but I keep receiving repeated values.