# Select distinct values of bool query elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a query that gets me some user post data from an elastic index. I am happy with that query, though I need to make it return rows with unique usernames. Current, it displays relevant posts by users, but it may display one user twice..

```
{
          "query": {
            "bool": {
              "should": [
                          { "match_phrase": { "gtitle": {"query": "voice","boost": 1}}},
                          { "match_phrase": { "gdesc": {"query": "voice","boost": 1}}},
                          { "match": { "city": {"query": "voice","boost": 2}}},
                          { "match": { "gtags": {"query": "voice","boost": 1}   }}
              ],"must_not": [
                          { "term": { "profilepicture": ""}}
              ],"minimum_should_match" : 1
            }
          }
}
```

I have read about aggregations but didn't understand much (also tried to use aggs but didn't work either).... any help is appreciated

Comment: do you want to display one post per user i.e if one user has multiple posts which match "voice", do you want to return only one? also could you post relevant part of the mapping?

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I want.. currently it displays multiple posts from same user matching that query. As for mapping I havent understood what it was, so I didnt add anything... mapping is the function that makes the index?

Comment: do you have field called userid or something like that?

Comment: Yeah, i have 'USERID','username','mates', 'description',
'category','country','city',profilepicture'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to use [terms aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html) to get all unique users and then use [top hits aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html) to get only one result for each user. This is how it looks.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "gtitle": {
              "query": "voice",
              "boost": 1
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "gdesc": {
              "query": "voice",
              "boost": 1
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "city": {
              "query": "voice",
              "boost": 2
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "gtags": {
              "query": "voice",
              "boost": 1
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "must_not": [
        {
          "term": {
            "profilepicture": ""
          }
        }
      ],
      "minimum_should_match": 1
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "unique_user": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "userid",
        "size": 100
      },
      "aggs": {
        "only_one_post": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 1
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "size": 0
}
```

Here `size` inside user aggregation is 100, you can increase that if you have more unique users(default is 10), also the outermost `size` is zero to get only aggregation results. One important thing to remember is your user ids have to be unique, i.e *ABC* and *abc* will be considered different users, you might have to make your userid `not_analyzed` to be sure about that. [More](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/mapping-intro.html) on that.

Hope this helps!!

Comment: A thank you is the minimum I could do for you... true gentleman !

Comment: glad I could help, pls consider accepting the answer, it will help future readers too.